# Resilience4j Circuit Breaker Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Circuit breaker will be in close or half-open state for unlimited time until the minimum number of calls achieved right? is there any way I can set when no call in amount of time it will turned to close state? Also is it possible to have minimum number of calls bigger than permitted number of calls in half open state? Thank you

Comment: The circuit breaker can only be sure of the service being back up once it has made sufficient calls (from the half-open state). It won't help anyone to forcefully close the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way I can set when no call in amount of time it will turned to close state?

No. In v1.6.0 we will add a `waitDurationInHalfOpenState` config parameter, but after the wait duration has elapsed and not enough calls have been recorded the CircuitBreaker transitions to OPEN and not CLOSED.

> is it possible to have minimum number of calls bigger than permitted number of calls in half open state

No, `minimumNumberOfCalls` is only used when the CircuitBreaker is closed. `permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState` is only used when the CircuitBreake

Comment: please can you help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407909/using-circuit-breaker-in-spring-boot